# Specifically defining hashHistory and yet --- Cannot read property 'getCurrentLocation' of undefined(…)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router, react-router-redux

I cannot figure out for my life why this setup does not work. I have been trying to resolve this for ~10 hours now. I am using `history 3.2.1`, `react-router 3.0.2` and `react-router-redux 4.0.7`, `webpack 1.14.0`

This setup works perfectly fine in development, but once packaged does not work because, it looks like, hashHistory is coming up undefined. The configureStore for production and development are not substantially different.

All involved variables are defined at the time they are executed as confirmed by devtools. I think the problem is with the loading of my `routes.js` perhaps (see images below)

Any help anyone can provide would be appreciated so much. Thanks for reading.

**Error:**

```
Cannot read property 'getCurrentLocation' of undefined(…)
```

**configureStore.production.js**

```
import { applyMiddleware, createStore, compose } from 'redux';
import { responsiveStoreEnhancer } from 'redux-responsive';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { routerMiddleware, push } from 'react-router-redux';
import rootReducer from '../reducers';
import storage from '../utils/storage';
import * as noteActions from '../actions/notes_actions';

var createHistory = require('history').createHashHistory;

const hashHistory = createHistory();


const actionCreators = {
  ...noteActions,
  push,
};


const router = routerMiddleware(hashHistory);

const enhancer = compose(
  responsiveStoreEnhancer,
  applyMiddleware(thunk, router),
  storage(),
);

export default function configureStore(initialState: Object | void) {
  return createStore(rootReducer, initialState, enhancer);
}
```

**Index.js**

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import storage from 'electron-json-storage';
import { syncHistoryWithStore } from 'react-router-redux';
import * as applicationUtils from './utils/functions';
import configureStore from './store/configureStore';
import myRoutes from './routes';
import './app.global.css';

var Router = require('react-router').Router;

var createHistory = require('history').createHashHistory;


let applicationState;
let stateKeyPresent;
let createStore;
let myHistory;
const hashHistory = createHistory();

function createStoreFunction() {
    createStore = configureStore(applicationState);
    myHistory = syncHistoryWithStore(hashHistory, createStore);
    render(
        <Provider store={createStore}>
        <Router history={myHistory} routes={myRoutes} />
        </Provider>,
        document.getElementById('root')
        );
}

storage.keys((err, keys) => {
    if (err) throw err;

    for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        if (keys[i] === 'state') {
            stateKeyPresent = keys[i];
        }
    };
});

let getStoredState = new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
    storage.get('state', (err, data) => {
        if (!stateKeyPresent) {
            applicationState = {};
            resolve();
        } else if (data) {
            applicationState = JSON.parse(data);
            resolve();
        } else {
            applicationState = {};
            resolve();
        }
    });
});

getStoredState.then(() => {
    createStoreFunction()
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try uninstalling the `history` npm module from your package dependency.

**React-router dependencies:**

```
  "dependencies": {
    "history": "^3.0.0",
    "hoist-non-react-statics": "^1.2.0",
    "invariant": "^2.2.1",
    "loose-envify": "^1.2.0",
    "warning": "^3.0.0"
  },
```

`React-router` has already dependency upon it and correct `history` version will be installed with `react-router` installation.

You don't need to install it separately.

try

```
npm uninstall --save history react-router
```

and then

```
install --save react-router@your_version
```

again.

Check if it works.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Unfortunately I installed it as an attempt to resolve this issue. Using the history built into react-router results in the same.

Comment: has it been uninstalled correctly? Just asking to make sure that issue is not any other. Have you checked your `package.json` whether it has correct dependencies?

Comment: Yes everything has the correct dependencies as best I can tell. `npm` doesn't inform me of anything wrong, invalid peers, missing dependencies, etc, and I can't find any myself either.